# How do I tell gunicorn to use a proxy server when making outbound calls?

Tags: django, docker, gunicorn

I have a Django web application being served up by gunicorn, running in a Docker container.  My Django app needs to access an AWS and it's failing.  I believe this is because it is all running behind a corporate firewall and I need to somehow tell gunicorn to use our proxy server.  How do I do that?  The documentation isn't clear (to me).  Thanks.

Comment: This is lacking information. What is the error? What are the logs? How are you launching the container? What is the `Dockerfile`? What have you tried to fix it? What is the piece of code needing to use a proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gunicorn is not involved in outgoing requests.

In your `Dockerfile` you can do:

```
ENV HTTP_PROXY="http://10.10.10.10:8000"
ENV HTTPS_PROXY="http://10.10.10.10:1212"
```

With whatever the proxy URLs are (or just set the environment variables some other way).

That might work for some libraries (but not all). E.g. the AWS CLI respects those: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-proxy.html